# Stop the background service after particular time in android

Tags: android, time, android-service, alarmmanager

Hi i need to stop the Background service which is already started after particular time.I will get the duration from server for when to stop the service.I have tried the Alarm Manager in android.

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // Start every 30 seconds
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60*1000, pintent);
        Log.e(TAG, "Service started in Activity");
```

This above code is starting the service after every one minute.But i dont want to start the service.I need to stop the service after a minute.How to do that.Is that possible to do with Alarm Manager.Please guide me.

Comment: Just call your stopService() after one minute is elapsed? Use a timer or a Local broadcast receiver

Comment: I dont know the exact time.Here for example i mentioned one minute.

Comment: The time starts as soon as your service starts, start counting one minute from that instance of time? Or if you are getting the time duration from the server, make a generic function which excepts time duration runs a thread for that duration and calls stopService accordingly? Simple?

Comment: look over the answer's provided below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

add parameter to your pendingIntent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("param_name", "end");
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Override [onStartCommand()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) method in your Service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try{
        String parameter = intent.getStringExtra("param_name");
        if(parameter.equals("end")){
            stopSelf();
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
    }
}
```

Also you can try to use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in your service:

Handler variable:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 1: {
                stopSelf();
            }break;
        }
    }
}
```

Delayed task:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.I have tried the OnStartCommand code in Service class.But I am getting error as PENDING_EXTRA_ACTION cannot be resolved to a variable.Please help me.

Comment: I'm sorry. I answered some incorrect. Use "param_name" instead. I've updated my post.

Comment: Note: you need to use that parameter when you want to stop service only.

Comment: Thanks.Its working but onStartCommand is called immediately.But i need to call few minutes or hours.Please guide me.

Comment: May be you need to increase the second parameter of setRepeating() method? For example: alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60*1000, 60*1000, pintent);

Comment: Hi Your code is working fine.But After using  onStartCommand method, onStart method is not called.Please guide me.

Comment: onStart() method was deprecated in API level 5 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart(android.content.Intent, int)

Answer (score 0):

Create the timer task to stop the service and assign the delay time which you are getting from your server

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {
   @Override
   public void run () {
       // your code here to stop the service ...
   }
 };
```

// schedule the task to run assign the time (DelayTime) which you are getting from server

```
timer.schedule (hourlyTask, DelayTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

So what is the particular time.

You can do 1 thing make note of the starting time of the service. and if you want to stop the service after a specified duration or the specific time get the system current time compare it with that time if it match's stop the service. this should resolve the problem.

Tell me if it works for you..
======>
Just Follow the steps provided steps below:

1. Use sharedprefrence to save the start time of the service.
2. If your not familiar to shearedprefrence    URL:http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/
3. Then in the service onStart method get the system current time if it
   matches the time stop the service.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an broadcast receiver:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // this will return current time

 // if you want to trigger after 1 minute then add into calender object

 cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
intentAlarm.setAction("My_Action");
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE, intentAlarm,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// set the alarm for particular time
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

AlarmReciever .java

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     //  call method to stop service 

    }
}
```

Also declare this  AlarmReceiver class in menifest file

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever" >

    </receiver>
```

Comment: I have tried your code.But AlarmReceiver class is not getting called.I have used Log to print something in logcat after AlarmReceiver is called.But nothing is shown in logcat.

Comment: and Alarm receiver is not getting called because i think you have not declared it in menifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
> here i used the countdowntime for 30second 
 after 30second call stopself() method it will stop your 
 services..u can also do what ever u want on finsih you can also pass a 
 notification to the user....
       new  CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long l) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //r u can also pass a notification
        stopSelf();
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: oky thanks for your suggsetion i will try to explain the code also...