# Stop background service only if no more work

Tags: android, android-service

I use a service to process intents with `ContentResolver` in the background.
Each new intent calls starts the service and the service stops itself once the processing is over.

This creates an issue where new intent starts a service run but the previous service run is still processing, resulting in killing the new run before its processing is over.

I thought about adding some kind of static 'nunInstances' in the service and stop it only of it's 1.

Another option is leaving the service running. I've tried looking for information about it's validity and side effects but came up empty.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569769/stop-the-background-service-after-particular-time-in-android

Comment: @asadali not the same, the other question relates to scheduling `stopService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IntentService`, which acts as a work queue. You can send it work to do with `startService()` as many times as you like. The work is performed serially, one after another. When the last work unit has been performed the `Service` stops itself.

Or you use a regular `Service` and queue the work yourself in `onStartCommand()`. When you have no more work to do, you call `stopSelf()`.

**NOTE:** Android will not create more than one instance of a `Service`. Your concern about having multiple instances of the `Service` running is not necessary. If something calls `startService()` and the `Service` is already running, Android **does not** create a new instance of the `Service`. It just called `onStartCommand()` on the running instance and passes the `Intent` as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  the num of instances I mentioned was actually the jobs queue length (wrong naming), the solution sounds really good, I just wonder, what would happen if I'll never call `stopSelf()` ?

Comment: That depends what you return from `onStartCommand()`. If you return `START_STICKY` Android will restart your `Service` automatically if it is killed. However, you can return other values and then Android will not restart your `Service` if it gets killed.

Comment: But is it OK to keep my `Service` alive all the time (assuming I use `START_NOT_STICKY` and never calls `stopSelf()` ?

Comment: It would be better if you shut it down when it isn't needed. But Android will do that for you.